# AnguIarJS: how do I edit a single background image to have a different background size than the rest

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am editing a couple of webpages. Each page has a main background image that is set to the size "cover"

HTML: (main file)

```
<div id="main-content" class="main-content">
<div class="main-content__main-image" ng-if="settings['mainImage'] !== 
null">
<style ng-if="settings['mainImageText']">
.main-content__mainImage {
background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url({{ 
settings["mainImage"] }}) top no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position-y: 50%;
}
</style>
<style ng-if="!settings['mainImageText']">
.main-content__mainImage {
background: url({{ settings["mainImage"] }}) top no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position-y: 50%;
}
</style>
```

in the JS file, the main images for each page are generated like this:

```
App.controller("historyCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.applySettings({
theHeader: "Our History",
theTitle: "Our History",
mainImage: "picture01.jpg",  
mainImageText: "",  
section: [
//etc
```

For every controller, the main image is fixed to the "cover" size since that is the template. However, some of the pictures are too big/small and I want to use the CSS "contain" background-size property. Ex:

```
background-size: contain;
```

How do I do this without changing the rest of the pictures being set as 'cover' ?

Answer (score 0):

The *simplest* solution given your setup is to add the style in the controller:

```
App.controller("historyCtrl", function($scope) {
angular.element('.main-content__mainImage').css('backgroundSize', 'contain');
$scope.applySettings({
    theHeader: "Our History",
    theTitle: "Our History",
    mainImage: "picture01.jpg",  
    mainImageText: "",  
    contains: true,
    section: [
   //etc
```

However, in general you should use angular to assign and remove classes to elements, not modify styles directly. `style` tags should not be included in the `body` (let alone even being embedded). By doing so you're mixing concerns. The HTML body is the *structure* of the data you're presenting, the *presentation* is a separate concern.

A better solution might add a boolean `containBackground` flag to your settings, and then in your HTML, use the `ng-class` attribute on your background container: `ng-class="{'contain-bg': settings['containBackground']}"`. Finally you would add class definition to your external CSS: `.contian-bg { background-size: contain }`